# redcarpet markdown - execute javascript code

Tags: javascript, ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I am created documentation using `tripit/slate`. All documentation content is in `.md` file. slate is using `redcarpet` markdown engine. Now when I put `<script>` tag as below in markdown:

````
```
<script>document.write(window._restapiurl);</script>
```
````

it will be converted to `&lt;script&gt;document.write(window._restapiurl);&lt;/script&gt;` in html. And the statement is in `<pre>` tag so will render as `<script>document.write(window._restapiurl);</script>` on page. The statement prints the path of an api endpoint.

I want to execute this statement on a page which means the statement should print the value of a varible `window._restapiurl`. If I manually write the `<script>` tag in html after page build, the statement will be executed and print the value of a variable.

**Update:**

tried with `:escape_html => true, :filter_html => true` in `config.rb` but it didn't work.

**more update**
I need to execute javascript statement in my language selector `curl` tab.

**more update**
Even If I remove triple ticks ```, the `script` tag does not execute. It just prints the `script` statement on a page.

**How do I execute javascript code written in markdown ??? So that I don't need to update the api endpoint path whenever new version is released and I can manage it by changing the value of variable only.**

Comment: Any chance to get it works ???

Comment: you shouldn't use the triple ticks (```) before and after your code since that is actually used to display code.

Comment: @mb21- I've used ``` for the `curl` language tab.

Comment: @mb21 - Even If I remove triple ticks ``` the `script` tag does not execute. It just prints the statement on a page.

Comment: `escape_html` should be `false`, not true. But anyway, this wreaks of a bad idea. The whole idea of markdown is to let people safely use a subset of html without writing HTML. If you trust people to add `script` tags, then just give them a regular HTML textfield.

Comment: @Mohamad - I don't need to give people to add `script` tag. I will write `<script>document.write(window._restapiurl);</script>` in md which needs to be executed on rendered html page.

Comment: @mb21 - need to put `<script>` statement in `<pre>` tag to get it executed.

Answer (score 0):

In md file I've replaced

````
```
url of api endpoint 
```
````

with below code

```
<pre>
     <script>document.write(window._restapiurl);</script>
</pre>
```

This will execute `javascript` statement in darkbox of `tripit/slate` documenation format.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to put this inside a code block ? If no, just put the script tag inside your Markdown file (or even, FWIW, write `<pre><code>` yourself). Otherwise, you can't easily do that. The fact is that by default, Redcarpet's HTML render object will escape any HTML tag inside code blocks. Your only option is to implement a custom render object. You can rely on the fact that the code yielded to the `block_code` method isn't HTML-escaped:

```
class CustomRender < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code, lang)
    "<pre>" \
      "<code class=\"#{lang}\">#{code}</code>" \
    "</pre>"
  end
end
```

And then pass this object to your `Redcarpet::Markdown` instance:

```
Redcarpet::Markdown.new(CustomRender, fenced_code_blocks: true)
```

Moreover, you're maybe doing it wrong. If it's just about inserting some special values inside your code snippets, then you may want to use a special syntax inside your snippets and replace it with your very own values. You can do that inside a custom render object again, using `String#gsub` or `String#%` on the given `code` variable.

Have a nice day!